# Unable to place any folders or icons on Desktop

Tags: 18.04, desktop-icons

Recently I have stopped being able to place any icons present in the home/Desktop directory onto the actual visible desktop.

I believe this issue started after an update since I don't recall making any tweaks to settings that could have caused this.

To reiterate, there are no issues with the Desktop directory itself, the issue is the inability to place folders or icons of any sort onto the desktop.

Comment: Rebooting fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the desktop icon feature (if it is disabled for some reason) by running the following command in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Then reboot your system.

Comment: Does not solve the problem, the problem is with folders as well. Currently desktop is blank. Earlier if I would drag a subdir of Desktop onto there it would stick but now it just bounces back

Comment: --version returns: GNOME nautilus 3.26.4

Comment: Oops, sorry bout that, 
GNOME Shell 3.28.4
Command returns True

Comment: I don't see anything out of the place! Are you in a Wayland session? What does `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` say? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: I'll try all those and get back, thank you

Comment: Rebooting fixed the issue. Not sure what caused this though.

Comment: Yes, the command in the answer may require a reboot sometimes to work properly. I have edited the answer accordingly.